# Number plate localization in bulk of images

Tags: c++, opencv

I have got bulk of car images and want to perform automatic number plate recognition but i am stuck at localization phase .I want to get license plate individually as output on which i can perform recognition.Here is my code for localization:

```
int main(int args,char* argv)
{
//String filename;
//filename="";
cv::Mat image=cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Sarora\\Downloads\\Images\\frame_1375.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::Mat img;
cv::Mat img_sobel;
cv::Mat grad_x, grad_y;
cv::Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;
cv::Mat imgContours;

//vector <Plate>result;

cv::cvtColor(image, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(img, img, cv::Size(5,5));
//cv::namedWindow("Img1.jpg", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

//sobel filter applied on image..............................................................................................

cv::Sobel(img, grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0,3,1,0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
 convertScaleAbs( grad_x, abs_grad_x );

cv::Sobel(img, grad_y, CV_16S, 0, 1,3,1,0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
 convertScaleAbs( grad_y, abs_grad_y );

 addWeighted( abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, img_sobel );

cv::imwrite("Img2.jpg",img_sobel);

//Threshold the image...................................................................................................................

cv::Mat Thresh_img;
threshold(img_sobel, Thresh_img, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU+CV_THRESH_BINARY);
//imshow("Threshold", Thresh_img);

//Morphological close operation applied................................................................................................

cv::Mat element1=cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));
cv::morphologyEx(Thresh_img,Thresh_img,CV_MOP_CLOSE,element1);
cv::imwrite("Close1.jpg",Thresh_img);
//cv::waitKey(5000);

//find Contours of whole image......................................................................................................

std::vector <std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
cv::findContours(Thresh_img, contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
//cv::drawContours(image,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),3);

cv::imwrite("Contours1.jpg",image);
std::vector <std::vector<cv::Point>>::iterator itc= contours.begin();
std::vector <cv::RotatedRect> rects;
 //vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(rects.size());
    //vector<Rect> boundRect(rects.size());

//Remove patch not inside the limits of aspect ratio and area..................................................................................

while (itc!=contours.end()) {
cv::RotatedRect mr= cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(*itc));

if( !verifySizes(mr))
   { itc= contours.erase(itc); 
}else { 
    ++itc; 
   rects.push_back(mr);
  } 
}
cv::Mat drawing;
 vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly(rects.size());
    vector<cv::Rect> boundRect(rects.size());
//Draw contours
    cv::Mat output;
    image.copyTo(output);
    for(int i=0;i<rects.size();i++)
 {
    approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 10, true);
    boundRect[i] = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]));
}
//cv::imwrite("Contours.jpg", output);
        for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(output, contours_poly, i, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 1, 8, vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());
        //rectangle(output, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 3, 8, 0); 
 }
 cv::imwrite("drawing1.jpg",output);
}
bool verifySizes(cv::RotatedRect mr){

    float error=0.4;
    //Set a min and max area. All other patches are discarded
    int min= 5; // minimum area
    int max=1000;  // maximum area

    //Get only patches that match
    float rmin= 1;
    float rmax= 10;

    int area= mr.size.height * mr.size.width;
    float r= (float)mr.size.width / (float)mr.size.height;
    if(r<1)
        r= (float)mr.size.height / (float)mr.size.width;

    if(( area < min || area > max ) || ( r < rmin || r > rmax )){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have performed sobel filter,Threshold(OTSU+binary),Morphological operation CLOSE,findContours(),removal of one not inside limits of area and aspect ratio and approxPolyDP on the image[This is my input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nguQM.jpg)

[This is approxPolyDP image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do6WH.jpg)

Problem is output image is not forming rectangles around License plate.Can anyone tell what is wrong in the code and also how can i proceed further to automatically find license plates in bulk of images?I am confused.

Thank you

Comment: ... good luck ...

Comment: When you can't do it on one image reliably, the question of bulk processing is moot -- solve one problem at a time.

Comment: @swati That said, I think you need to go back and focus on getting better input. Minimize the angle in respect to direction of motion of the vehicles to reduce perspective distortion. Good illumination (vehicles are in shadow) for fast exposure minimizing motion blur. Focus (seems to me the plant in fg is sharp, the vehicles not so much). Field of view + resolution -- right now more than half of your image will never contain a car, yet you still process it. The usable area is maybe 800x400 pixels (a fraction of the frame). As a result, the symbols on the plates are maybe 8 pixels tall at best.

Comment: I can't find the paper right now to quote, but from what I remember at this size reliable recognition is unlikely -- you'd need something like 2-3 times that. To be frank, I can't even read those plates myself.

Comment: @ Dan Mašek Thank you for helping me out . I really appreciate it. Other than above procedure for number plate localization is there any other method which is more efficient than this one ? I need fast performance and high accuracy both. Thank you for help.